# What blog post are you working on?

Tags: discussion, blog

Since we're [soon getting a blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128318/right-people-to-contact-to-get-a-beta-community-blog-on-blog-overflow), its probably a good idea to start thinking of the first articles we're writing.

(If you haven't signed up to be an author, see [Call for participation: Cooking blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/call-for-participation-cooking-blog). If you need ideas, or just want to share some, see [Question ideas for our blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-a-hypothetical-blog).)

So, if you're *actively* working on a post for the blog, please post (and keep updated via editing) answer saying:

- what you're working on
- if you can, an idea of when you'll finish
- progress updates, if its something that takes a while (e.g., doing an experiment in cheese making)
- any help you want from the rest of us
- anything else you want to add to help us all coordinate with each other.

**UPDATE** If you are a **new contributor**, you need an account for writing your post. When you start writing, please 1) post here what you are working on and 2) contact the blog admins at cooking.se.blog@gmail.com to get an invitation. Please provide an e-mail address to which your account will be registered, and your cooking.stackexchange account name.

Comment: at present the link to the blog from cooking.stackexchange.com is only present if the user is not logged in.

Comment: @CosCallis I saw one, but only a new post notification. It went away once I clicked it once. But you ought to open a new question on meta for that...

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was 'by design' or what..

Answer (score 2):

I will try baking the cookies I mentioned in this post: [How to create fruity or grassy shortbread cookies?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22572/how-to-create-fruity-or-grassy-shortbread-cookies). As I didn't get answers, the main focus will be to show an experiment and tell what functions and what doesn't. The tastes I want to try are dried lavender, freeze-dried raspberries, matcha (I got a source, yay) and orange zest. Maybe also raspberry leather for comparison. Expect documentation of the process with pics and text.

Current status: Post went live May 23 2012 @ 1200 UTC

Comment: Hey those are all going to taste good. What kind of experiment is this!

Comment: @Jefromi an experiment in gaining weight, I expect.

Answer (score 2):

I intend to do a blog post on an experiment for acid vs enzyme set cheeses and the difference in their meltability.

This started as an argument in a question and I couldn't find any authoritative answers online.

This will take a while (I'm doing an experiment in cheese making) but I will post updates if/when I get around to it.

Answer (score 2):

Experiment on the same bread, just at different hydrations. Will probably wind up with from 50%–100%, but it'll depend on how well it works... Also, won't be completely scientific (e.g., don't have a commercial proofbox to precisely control temp & humidity) but I'll try and keep variables to a minimum.

Current status: Post went live May 9th 2012 @ 1200 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

The next major Jewish holiday is Shavuot, on May 27-28. Will the blog be up and running by then? (Please let me know as soon as possible, so I can start writing.)

If yes, I'll write an article on the food traditions for the holiday It's one of the few where the tradition is to make dairy foods, and I can explain why and a bit about the difference between dairy, meat, and pareve (neither dairy nor meat) in kosher food. I'd be happy to finish the article with some family recipes from my grandmother (cheesecake) and great-grandmother (cheese balls).

Current status: Post went live 2012-06-04

Comment: The blog *is* up and running, it just doesn't have content yet (though two posts are in progress). FYI, the URL is http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: It would be great if you can start writing. As @derobert mentioned, the infrastructure is in place. I can give you an account for our wordpress instance, and need an e-mail address for this. If you are OK with me creating the account for the address you saved in your cooking.stackexchange profile, please say it here (I can see this address as a mod). If you would like me to use a different address, come into the chat room The Frying Pan (there is a link on the main site) and you can tell me what address to use without you having to post it somewhere crawlable.

Comment: Go ahead and use the email in my profile.

Comment: Curious if you have a status update, May 23 is approaching.

Answer (score 2):

I am preparing an article about a blind taste test I am conducting to determine the importance of letting a compound butter "rest" before serving. Spun off from the following: [Will flavors marry in compound butter if given sufficient time to rest?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/will-flavors-marry-in-compound-butter-if-given-sufficient-time-to-rest)

Comment: Cool. When you've got a draft, let one of us know. Best way is probably in the chat room.