# Call for participation: Cooking blog

Tags: discussion, blog

As discussed before, we would like to have our own blog. The StackExchange community team will probably be nice enough to create one for us - if we commit ourselves to creating good content in a reasonable rhythm. This question is for the people who want to participate as authors.

An author should either come up with own ideas for a post, or pick one of the commonly proposed ideas, and create a post based on it. I am aware that we all have jobs and lives outside of cooking and the StackExchange network, so we can't have too rigorous a schedule for writing. But we still have to be able to make some kind of plan, and keep the blog more or less regular. So, I will ask you to also indicate the average frequency (in weeks or months) in which you think you can write a post.

It is clear that some of us will be willing to write more frequently than others; this isn't a bad thing. We need every post we can get, to avoid the blog dying due to lack of content. Even if you can only write one post a year, I would prefer you to indicate it here, instead of thinking that it is so little that it isn't worth it. We, the community,  can profit from your experience, even if you don't have the time to write more.

There is no firm schedule for the blog yet. But we have discussed in chat a schedule of one post every two weeks, and if we get more material, we can use it for specials in between. This way, even the most frequent contributors won't need to write more than once every few weeks. If we can get enough people committed, we should be able to accommodate more and less frequent writers without a problem.

If you have ideas for a special topic or format you want to write, you can indicate it in your answer. (For example, a professional can promise us to deliver a series of "insider" stories from a restaurant kitchen). But this is not mandatory, if you can't think of such a thing, just leave your name and the projected frequency. If you want to write, but can't come up with topics, take a look at the current [post ideas](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-a-hypothetical-blog) as well as the [scope definition](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/scope-of-a-hypothetical-blog). Or come into the Frying Pan to discuss further ideas. Everybody is welcome!

**UPDATE** If you are a **new contributor**, you need an account for writing posts. To get an account, 1) post [here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/what-blog-post-are-you-working-on) what you are working on and 2) contact the blog admins at cooking.se.blog@gmail.com to get an invitation. Please provide an e-mail address to which your account will be registered, and your cooking.stackexchange account name.

Comment: We're excited to see you guys committing to writing for this blog! You'll have one set up soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128321/166017

Answer (score 2):

I think I could also manage one post per month. I'd be willing to write recipe comparisons and information on cooking traditions for Jewish holidays.

Answer (score 2):

Reading about the concept of product reviews mentioned in this [answer](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1404/1685), I thought that I'd mention here that I'd be willing to do some product review / experimentation in the style of http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/tail-light-review/.  (But with somewhat fewer products and charts, I think.)

I could do **Cookies on parchment paper vs. [Silpat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001079VBG) vs. bare cookie sheet**.  I have all of those things, but I could do more if I had more equipment.

Comment: Why not start with what you have? Comparisons can be extremely useful, but as you add more options they quickly become extremely time-consuming to test thoroughly. The great thing about a blog is that you can always revisit a topic later if you come up with something better...

Comment: Curious if you'd like to write a post soon? We're looking for some much shorter articles (compared to what we've published so far), too. If you'd like to do a few paragraphs on the cookies, with some photos if possible, that'd be welcome (I realize its summer and you may not want to heat up the oven...)

Comment: I will have time to do this in the second half of next week.  I'm glad to know there's still interest in this.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to write a blog post once in a while, but not on a monthly basis. There are periods when I'm extremely busy, but normally I know them beforehand.

As for topics, it doesn't matter that much to me. I could introduce you to the wonderful world of Belgian cuisine if wanted. I prefer baking over cooking, and I prefer baking sweets over baking savory things.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very glad to write for the new blog. I can also do the admin duty, if needed.

I can write a post every four to eight weeks. I don't have a full-blown "series" idea yet, but I can imagine that doing hands-on experiments would be my thing. So, for now I commit myself as a general writer, and if things go well, could imagine specializing later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to write baking entries.  Frequency, probably about once every couple of months for a large one, or shorter ones more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written a blog before, but I think I could manage to do at least one post per month. Eventually (once I get the hang of it), I think I could do more often.

Coming up with topics is always what I've found hardest about writing. Right now, I've posted two ideas to the idea thread, both of which could be an ongoing series (e.g., vary hydration -> vary something else). And there are several other good suggestions there. So I'm covered for a bit.

Also, as mentioned on chat, I volunteer to do any required administrative duty. I also volunteer to be an editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely willing to be an admin, if desired. I can also definitely help edit/proofread!

I can contribute some, but I don't think I want to commit to a certain frequency of posts at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'll contribute, likewise up for admin/editing duties if required. I should be able to manage at least one post a month.

Comment: Curious if you'd like to write a post soon? We're looking for some much shorter articles (compared to what we've published so far), too.

Comment: It would have to be a short one, I have a couple of articles to write for the photo blog already. What kind of thing did you have in mind?

Comment: Hmmm, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-our-blog has a lot of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I would commit to writing the blog posts that I suggested in the other thread at an every 4 - 8 weeks time frame. After that, I'd need to reassess (my ability to come up with new topics with a kid, since my cooking is currently non-existent), but the blog should either be working or not by that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy to contribute. I maintain my own with a focus on vegan foods and would be down with a post every 1-2 weeks, and am happy to do copy work.

Comment: Curious if you'd like to write a post soon? We're looking for some much shorter articles (compared to what we've published so far), too. It'd be awesome if you actually did a post every  week, but much less frequent is fine too... We're trying to get above a post every other week.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it would be interesting to participate in. I would be willing to contribute, probably monthly. In particular I would focus on meat dishes and outdoor grilling.

Comment: We've officially started; our first post went up today. Are you still interested in writing? If so, either send an email to cooking.se.blog@gmail.com (see UPDATE in the question) or pop into chat and bug us.

Answer (score 0):

In theory I'd love to do this, but on a practical basis I'm months behind on my tech blog, and haven't posted to my personal cooking blog since February ...