# (How) Can people contribute to the Seasoned Advice Blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I thought I remembered the existence of such a blog and I just realized it's [linked](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/) in the fancy "new" header.

The latest post is well over a year old. Is there a process for submitting content for the blog or has it essentially been abandoned?

Excuse my ignorance. I searched meta and found nothing. I couldn't find any info on the blog itself or on blogoverflow.com

Reading through the blog tag, I've found some planning threads including [Question ideas for our blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-our-blog), [What blog post are you working on?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/what-blog-post-are-you-working-on), and [Scope of a hypothetical blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/scope-of-a-hypothetical-blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! According to a note in [Call for participation: Cooking blog](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/call-for-participation-cooking-blog)

> If you are a new contributor, you need an account for writing posts.
> To get an account, 1) post here what you are working on and 2) contact
> the blog admins at cooking.se.blog@gmail.com to get an invitation.
>
> Please provide an e-mail address to which your account will be
> registered, and your cooking.stackexchange account name.

That passage was added at the end of April 2012.